# Turning a vector of vectors acquired from a simulation into a matrix. Numeric problem

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I am just trying to do a basic thing but I can't seem to figure out what the problem is and I can't find answers here that are to problems exactly like mine. If anyone already knows of an answer to this elsewhere, feel free to link that.

I have a simulation that generates a vector, and I have set up my simulation such that it grabs the generate vector and makes it an element of another vector. After I run the simulation multiple times, I would like to make the vector of vectors into a matrix, but it the console output is always this:

```
 >   agx1     
[1,] Numeric,7
[2,] Numeric,7
```

My simulation pretty much does the following:

```
agnx1 = c()

#some stuff happens

agnx1[i] = x1

#iteration number two takes place

agnx1[i+1] = x1

#etc..

#Now say I have

agx1[1] = c(0.796399, 0.865736, 0.885808, 0.896138, 0.896138, 0.850385, NA)

#and

agx1[2] = c(0.796399, 0.856540, 0.881432, 0.900808, 0.900808, 0.857664, NA)

#and therefore, agx1 is a vector of vectors. But whenever I try something like..

cagx1 = cbind(agx1[1:2])

#or

cagx1 = as.matrix(agx1)

# I just get:   

 [,1]     
[1,] Numeric,7
[2,] Numeric,7
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: I would like the vector to have two columns, one for each ```[i]``` if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing all of the data, but perhaps `agx1` is a list. Try using `do.call`.

```
do.call(cbind, agx1)
```

**Edit**

Base R `cbind` doesn't have functionality to work on a list. Consider this:

```
cbind(agx1[[1]],agx1[[2]])
```

That works because you have unlisted the first and second elements and passed them as vectors to `cbind`.

You get around this problem using `do.call`. `help(do.call)` says:

> Description
>
> do.call constructs and executes a function call from a name or a
>   function and a list of arguments to be passed to it.

Thus, `do.call` helps you call `cbind(agx1[[1]], agx1[[2]], ...` and so on until the end of the list by constructing the `cbind` function call from the list of `agx1` arguments.

Comment: That worked!! Do you mind me asking what that does?

Comment: Sure, see my edit for a description.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `agx1` is something like this :

```
agx1 <- list(c(0.796399, 0.865736, 0.885808, 0.896138, 0.896138, 0.850385, NA),
             c(0.796399, 0.856540, 0.881432, 0.900808, 0.900808, 0.857664, NA))
```

You could use `dplyr::bind_cols`

```
dplyr::bind_cols(agx1)

#     V1     V2
#   <dbl>  <dbl>
#1  0.796  0.796
#2  0.866  0.857
#3  0.886  0.881
#4  0.896  0.901
#5  0.896  0.901
#6  0.850  0.858
#7     NA     NA
```